# MEMORY(HEAP) vs. InnoDB in a Read and Write Environment

Tags: mysql, memory, locking, innodb

I want to program a real-time application using MySQL.

It needs a small table (less than 10000 rows) that will be under heavy read (scan) and write (update and some insert/delete) load. I am really speaking of 10000 updates or selects per second. These statements will be executed on only a few (less than 10) open mysql connections.

The table is small and does not contain any data that needs to be stored on disk. So I ask which is faster: InnoDB or MEMORY (HEAP)?

My thoughts are:

1. Both engines will probably serve SELECTs directly from memory, as even InnoDB will cache the whole table. What about the UPDATEs? (innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit?)
2. My main concern is the locking behavior: InnoDB row lock vs. MEMORY table lock. Will this present the bottleneck in the MEMORY implementation?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 5):

If you're really having to have that much concurrent updates, it's almost certain that innodb will perform better, as HEAP tables only have table-level locks, not row-level locks like Innodb.

If you're starting from scratch I would investigate using MySQL 5.5 or Percona's XtraDB as they both contain many scalability improvements over the stock MySQL 5.1.

Comment: Thanks! Of what improvements in MySQL 5.5 are you thinking?
Is it just performing better on the same table definitions, or does the design have to be significantly different. If yes, how do I find out which parts should be implemented differently in 5.5. compared to 5.1? Any directions

Comment: It should perform better on the same definitions, by virtue of finer-grained locking in various internal innodb structures, and smarter adaptive algorithms. The speedup should be noticeable on multi-core boxes, in both IO and CPU bound workloads.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just a question of row locks - InnoDB also has MVCC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control so the readers won't even block writers.

But I think your question is missing the all important detail - what sort of data are you storing?  If you need to be able to recover post-crash MEMORY is not an option.

If you don't need to recover post crash, then why are you using a database?  Why not use something like memcached or redis?

Comment: Trusting on rock solid implementation not a bad idea. Knowing that need to perform operations on complex data structures, it would be hard on implement several operations (creating sub-collection, sorting, etc...) on cached data (not even counting possible bugs and required testing for it). Databases good on these kind of stuff, thus using them would be a huge relief for developer. By the way your solution is theoretically logical, and it would be better if you mention tools for performing operations that i said databases good on.